# How are Inspect.exe/UI Accessibility Checker causing my program to gracefully resume after null pointer access and what else can I do about it?

Tags: winapi, com, accessibility

The accessible objects in my custom table control are stored in a doubly linked list in the table itself (so they can be invalidated when the table window is destroyed). Right now, my `WM_GETOBJECT` handler contains the following erroneous code sequence (where `t` is the table and `ta` is the new accessible object):

```
ta->next = t->firstAcc;
t->firstAcc->prev = ta;
t->firstAcc = ta;
```

This is an error because when the linked list is empty, `t->firstAcc` will be `NULL`, so the second line will lead to a null pointer exception.

...except not. When Inspect.exe queries my table's accessible object, it seems to "intercept" the null pointer exception, bringing my program back to a stable state and repeating the process all over again a few times before finally giving up and just grabbing the standard accessible object instead. The program still runs and seems to run quite well!

And it's not just Inspect.exe; UI Accessibility Checker also exhibits this behavior too.

This is Inspect.exe 7.2.0.0 and UI Accessibility Checker 3.0, both running on Windows 7 64-bit. I forget if both came with Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop or not (with one of the Windows SDKs instead). The accessible objects are MSAA IAccessible objects because Windows XP compatibility is still required.

Obviously this makes debugging bugs like this problematic. So my questions are simple:

How are Inspect.exe and UI Accessibility Checker doing this? Is it special code that they share or is there something about MSAA or OLE or COM that does this?

Is there anything I can do about this? Neither of these programs have options to turn off the behavior. Could I just get the accessible object myself (posing as a client) to test this behavior? (That would work for the top-level object, but doing thorough tests for navigation would be a bit more painful.) And if so, would I need to initialize COM (for something in the same process) or run as administrator (because of UIPI)?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the CallStack, luke.

Comment: @manuell I'm not sure what you mean; I'm trying to make it so I *can* debug my COM objects effectively, and Inspect.exe doesn't have its own call stack feature...

Comment: @andiabs sorry for unclear comment. What I meant was; put a break point where you dereference nullptr and look at the call stack when that happens. Often, dll names and function names in the call stack (if you have the symbols) are useful.

Comment: Seems natural that Accessibility tools and Frameworks try to do their maximum to NOT make application crash. Like, setting an exception handler surrounding call to "application provided" code.

Comment: All right, thanks. I can try that later; at this point I plan on just jumping to UI Automation since it's a much better fit for my use case (but IDK when I'll start writing *that* code).

Comment: [Possible cause?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/20/10117963.aspx) Will need to dig out my old code and find out...

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of thing I thought But has to be in process. Only call stack can give details.